# Unix shell script to sort files depending on the 'date string' present in their file name

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to sort files in a directory, depending on the 'date string' attached in the file name, for example files looks as below
`SSA_F12_05122013.request.done`
`SSA_F13_12142012.request.done`
`SSA_F14_01062013.request.done`
Where 05122013,12142012 and 01062013 represents the dates in  format.
Please help me in providing a unix shell script to sort these files on the date string present in their file name(in descending and ascending order).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you tried to do this yourself, with which part did you get stuck?

Comment: John, I am beginner for this platform and have no idea how to do this. I tried using sort command, but not able to take the part of filename(which contains date) and sort files depending on that. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Find the person responsible for the naming pattern, and kick him hard in the backside for not making the pattern trivially sortable in the first place. Then find out if you couldn't change the pattern. YYYY-MM-DD is not only sortable, but also unambiguous. (If it weren't for `12142012`, I would not know which numbers in your examples are "month", and which ones are "day".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way with awk and sort:

```
ls -1|awk -F'[_.]' '{s=gensub(/^([0-9]{4})(.*)/,"\\2\\1","g",$3);print s,$0}'|sort|awk '$0=$NF'
```

if we break it down:

```
ls -1|
awk -F'[_.]' '{s=gensub(/^([0-9]{4})(.*)/,"\\2\\1","g",$3);print s,$0}'|
sort|
awk '$0=$NF'
```

the `ls -1` just example. I think you have your way to get the file list, one per line.

test a little bit:

```
kent$  echo "SSA_F13_12142012.request.done
SSA_F12_05122013.request.done
SSA_F14_01062013.request.done"|awk -F'[_.]' '{s=gensub(/^([0-9]{4})(.*)/,"\\2\\1","g",$3);print s,$0}'|
sort|
awk '$0=$NF'
SSA_F13_12142012.request.done
SSA_F14_01062013.request.done
SSA_F12_05122013.request.done
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... why call on heavyweights like awk and Perl when `sort` itself has the capability to define what exactly to sort by?

```
ls SSA_F*.request.done | sort -k 1.13,1.16 -k 1.9,1.10 -k 1.11,1.12
```

Each `-k` option defines a "sort key":

```
-k 1.13,1.16
```

This defines a sort key ranging from field 1, column 13 to field 1, column 16. (A field is by default delimited by whitespace, which your filenames don't have.)

If your filenames are varying in length, defining the underscore as field separator (using the `-t` option) and then addressing columns in the third field would be the way to go.

Refer to `man sort` for details. Use the `-r` option to sort in descending order.

Comment: Thanks Dev, you are correct, but if my file name length is variying,(for example SSA_F12_05122013.request.done and SSA_F9_05122013.request.done), then i think we cant proceed with the positions of characters in file name.Is there any solution for this??

Comment: Well, after kicking the responsible person yet again ;-) you could use `sort -f '_' -k 3.5,3.8 -k 3.1,3.2 -k 3.3,3.4`. (Making '_' the field separator, and addressing columns in the third field, i.e. the date.) Warning, not tested, use at your own risk (or rather, please test before inflicting on productive data).

Comment: Great! Helped a lot. Thanks. By the way, for seperator its -t and not -f.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -lrt *.done | perl -lane '@a=split /_|\./,$F[scalar(@F)-1];$a[2]=~s/(..)(..)(....)/$3$2$1/g;print $a[2]." ".$_' | sort -rn | awk '{$1=""}1'
```

Comment: You could also finally pipe though `awk '{print $NF}'` to get just the filename.

Comment: This is really helpful. Executing above command, getting error as
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
I tried executing below command removing 'awk' part, 
ls -lrt *.done | perl -lane '@a=split /_|\./,$F[scalar(@F)-1];$a[2]=~s/(..)(..)(....)/$3$2$1/g;print $a[2]." ".$_' | sort -rn
it's returning the results in sorted way as expected.
I am not sure for what we use awk command and also didn't understood the above command coz am having very minimal knowledge :).
Your answer is really helpful and any description on above command is pretty much appreciated.
Tnx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.done | perl -pe 's/^.*_(..)(..)(....)/$3$2$1$&/' | sort -rn | cut -b9-
```

this would do +

Comment: Thanks a lot Sidharth,, its working, but I am not able to understand the complete statement clearly :), can u please text in brief what each command in above statement is doing.

Comment: With the perl substitution command we are rearranging the date in YYYYMMDD format and attaching it to the beginning of the filename temporarily so that sort will function correctly. After sorting the first 8 characters are removed using cut -b9- You can refer [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) for perl regular expression syntax.

Comment: @SidharthC.Nadhan thanks for answer I am trying to pipe this with find commad but after cut find can not search files do you have any suggestion for that?